# How to avoid/remove writing the last comma in a row?

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable

I'm working with a `JTable` and CSV files, the thing is I have to save the data inserted in the table, and then reopen if the user needs to make some modifications. So far I can save and load CSV file created from the table I was talking about, but `BufferedWriter` object is adding a comma at the end of every row, which causes a new blank column when loading an existing CSV file.

Here's my code, I've tried to restrict this matter but it's been unsuccessfully.

```
if(jTable1.getModel()==this.m){
            File file = new File(this.tfSelectedSpreadsheet.getText().toString());
            if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()){
                file.delete();
            }
            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.tfSelectedSpreadsheet.getText().toString()),"UTF-8"));
            for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getColumnCount();i++){
                bfw.append(jTable1.getColumnName(i));
                if(i<jTable1.getColumnCount()) bfw.append(",");
                else bfw.newLine();
            }
            bfw.newLine();
            for(int i=0;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<jTable1.getColumnCount();j++){
                    bfw.append((String)jTable1.getValueAt(i,j));
                    if(j<jTable1.getColumnCount()) bfw.append(",");
                    bfw.newLine();
                }
                bfw.newLine();
            }
            bfw.close();
        }
```

And this is how the CSV file generated by this code looks like:

```
Link,Long,Lat,CRS,
R011,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R014,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R019,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R011,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R011,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R011,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R015,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
R014,120.1126,-33.5422,GDA94,
WANDA,25.12.1990,-37.0991,GDA90,
```

What could I do in order to fix this "comma" problem?

Comment: This is a common problem, and there's no "clever" solution that I know of.  You have to insert a test somewhere in the loop (or unroll the loop one iteration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(i<jTable1.getColumnCount()) bfw.append(",");
```

`i` will always be less then `jTable1.getColumnCount()`, remember, `Java` is `0` indexed, so the number of columns go from `0-jTable1.getColumnCount() - 1`

Try using something more like...

```
if(i< == Table1.getColumnCount() - 1) bfw.append(",");
```

...instead

Comment: @shmosel Based on the example code I stole it from, it was `i`, that's writing the column headers, but yes, it applies to all the places where the OP is testing `getColumnCount`

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the second loop.

Comment: Many thanks @MadProgrammer I followed your advice, I changed the condition into IF-clause.

Answer (score 10):

Since Java 8 you can use a [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
joiner.add("First");
joiner.add("Second");

String row = joiner.toString(); // produces "First,Second"
```

You can even define a prefix and suffix:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
joiner.add("First");
joiner.add("Second");

String row = joiner.toString(); // produces "[First,Second]"
```

If your data is already available as collection (or something else that can produce a [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)), you can also use the new stream API instead of writing another loop:

```
List<String> data = ...
String row = data.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Teach me something new +1

Comment: I'm not doing a lot of Java these days, but this is a handy Java 8 thing to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I always add the comma before the item unless the index is 0.

```
BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.tfSelectedSpreadsheet.getText().toString()),"UTF-8"));
for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getColumnCount();i++){
    if (i > 0) {
        bfw.append(",");
    }
    bfw.append(jTable1.getColumnName(i));
}
bfw.newLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to MadProgrammer I solved the problem by using this code, I hope it could help someone out there.

```
if(jTable1.getModel()==this.m){
            File file = new File(this.tfSelectedSpreadsheet.getText().toString());
            if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()){
                file.delete();
            }
            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.tfSelectedSpreadsheet.getText().toString()),"UTF-8"));
            for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getColumnCount();i++){
                bfw.append(jTable1.getColumnName(i));
                if(i<jTable1.getColumnCount()-1) bfw.append(",");//Here i changed the condition
                else bfw.newLine();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<jTable1.getColumnCount();j++){
                    bfw.append((String)jTable1.getValueAt(i,j));
                    if(j<jTable1.getColumnCount()-1) bfw.append(",");//Here i changed the condition
                    else bfw.newLine();
                }
            }
            bfw.close();
        }
```